# In a differences in differences model with continuous treatment, what is the parallel trends assumption?

Tags: difference-in-difference

How is there a parallel trends assumption if there is no formally defined treatment group?

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465167/how-does-the-parallel-trends-assumption-operate-when-there-are-multiple-interven

Comment: What do you mean by no “formally defined” treatment group? Do you mean different units start treatment at different times?

Comment: @ThomasBilach What I mean is that the since the treatment is not binary, there is no formal "treatment group" in the traditional sense of the term

Comment: @RobertF --> thank you for the link; I think it is addressing a slightly different question to the one that I am asking given that it is looking at multiple treatments as opposed to a single continuous treatment

Comment: You could still have a “group” in some sense. Do a subset of units start treatment at a particular point in time? Maybe some policy is introduced, or a new law is passed?

Comment: @ThomasBilach I am referring to the kind of treatment measured in the first answer to the question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152684/how-do-i-interpret-a-difference-in-differences-model-with-continuous-treatment

Comment: @ThomasBilach I mean not necessarily. There could be a policy that affects everyone but the effect is doses by an exogneous characteristic, which is a continuous variable. In that case you have everyone somehow treated by with different intensity, no group is a pure control.